# Proving the set $S=\left\{ \left(x,y\right);ax+by<c\right\} $ is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**Prove** the set $S=\left\{ \left(x,y\right);ax+by<c\right\} $ is
open

**My Approach** I know there are many methods of proving this.But
i find the method of proving every point to be interior point very
fundamental.Please help me with this method only.

Let $A=\left(x_{o},y_{o}\right)$$\in S$ Now i need to prove that
a Ball $B\left(A,r\right)$$\subset$$S$. I am unable to find any
Ball.

**Then i Saw Book's Approach** It says

$\left(x_{o},y_{o}\right)$$\in S$ $\Longrightarrow$$ax_{o}+by_{o}<c$$\Longrightarrow$I
Don't Understand how $ax_{o}+by_{o}<c$$\Longrightarrow$$\delta<\frac{|ax_{o}+by_{o}-c|}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}$

I know it is delta neighbourhood around $\left(x_{o},y_{o}\right)$.But
how did they get this expression

and how can we say N$_{\delta}$$\left(A\right)$$\subset$S

Comment: Do you know the "distance between point and line" formula in coordinate geometry?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг yes i know it is $\sqrt{\left(x-x_{o}\right)^{2}+\left(y-y_{o}\right)^{2}}$

Comment: @MohanSharma No, you don't know it. That's the formula for the distance between two points.

Comment: @KennyLau Yes okk now i remember i studied it in 10th standered

Comment: @MohanSharma The RHS of the expression containing $\delta$ is exactly that formula. With this in mind, it is almost obvious why this $\delta$ works.

Comment: You may have a look at this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1916424/72031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ be given by $(x,y) \mapsto ax+by$. It is a linear combination of the two standard projection maps, so it is continuous, so the pre-image of any open set is an open set, and in particular $S = \varphi^{-1}[(-\infty,c)]$ is the preimage of the open interval $(-\infty,c)$, so it is open.

Comment: is this theorem work proving for closed sets ?

Comment: The preimage of a closed set under a continuous function is a closed set. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/437837/328173) for a topological proof.

Comment: Sir please explain how $ax_{o}+by_{o}<c$$\Longrightarrow$$\delta<\frac{|ax_{o}+by_{o}-c|}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}$

Comment: See [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html).

Comment: Sharks.Kenny.Would like to have your take.Assume a,b,c positive. First quadrant the line ax+by -c=0 cuts a triangle, x intercept c/a, y intercept b/a. Choose any point (x_0,y_0) within triangle, i.e. below the line , I.e. ax0 +by_0 < c. Distance from this point to line is given by the quoted formula, call it d. Consider the circle around (x_0,y_0)with radius r=d/2 (for example). All points within the open "ball" are within triangle, I.e. ax_0+by_0 <c. Visually clear. Do not manage to prove this without some coordinate geometry .Any ideas?