# Prove that the set $\{(x,y): x=-y\}$ is open

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Prove that the set $\{(x,y): x=-y\}$ is open

I tried to use the definition of an open set, but failed to succeed.

Comment: Are you sure that the question isn't about the complement of this set?

Comment: Is open as a subset of what space with what topology?

Comment: This is not open in the standard basis. Perhaps this topology is built on some other basis you forgot to mention.

Comment: Possibly of interest :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2613163/proving-the-set-s-left-leftx-y-rightaxbyc-right-is-open/2613167#comment5398124_2613167

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Of course* you failed to succeed. It is *not* open. For instance, if $r>0$, $B\bigl((0,0),r\bigr)$ is not a subset of your set, although $(0,0)$ belongs to it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jose Carlos Santos pointed out, the set is not open:

your set is $A=\{\; (x,y)\; :\; x+y=0\; \}=f^{-1}(\{0\})$ for $f(x,y)=x+y$. Since $\{0\}$ is closed and $f$ is continuous (for the usual topology of the plane), it follows that $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is also closed.

In the plane $\mathbb R^2$, which is a connected set, the closed sets that are also open are $\mathbb R^2$ and the empty set $\emptyset$, so the set $A$ is not open.